# How to modify cognitive services TTS example to play the audio synthesized

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the python example of TTS that's provided [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/tree/master/Samples-Http/Python) and it all seem to be working fine:

```
$ python3 python_projects/TTSSample.py

Connect to server to get the Access Token
200 OK
Access Token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhMiOiJ1cm46bXMuY29nbml0[truncated]

Connect to server to synthesize the wave
200 OK
The synthesized wave length: 9040
```

However, my expectation is to hear the translated text spoken back directly from my computer, but that isn't happening.Am I missing any any steps?

What do I need to do hear an audible version of the synthesised text? I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) library, you need to install it first, then

```
data = response.read()
conn.close()
print("The synthesized wave length: %d" %(len(data)))

import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=16000,
                output=True)
stream.write(data)
stream.close()
```